# Cordova, Node.js, Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am running through this tutorial:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

I just created the project within my workspace with:

```
cordova create hello2 com.example.hello2 "Hello World 2"
```

cd into the dir

And now:

```
cordova platform add android
```

Gives me the following error:

```
The command `android` failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the `android` command (inside the tools/ folder) added to your path. Output: /bin/sh: android: command not found
```

My export path looks like this:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Documents/DevFolder/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/platform-tools:/Documents/DevFolder/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/tools
```

What's wrong with this path ?

Or what else could cause this error. And, yes I did install the Android SDK. 
According to this:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html

Comment: If `android` is added correctly to the path, you should be able to call it from the terminal. Try `which android` in a terminal, and report back please.

Comment: Thanks. I get no response for which android.

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` say?

Comment: Cool. Echo $PATH mentions the two paths (like mentioned above). Do these paths have to be absolute or relative to the Home Dir ? Right now I have it relative to the home Dir. Installing the android SDK, is just unzipping and putting the files in a Dir of my liking, right ? There is no building involved ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MacOS, but, to know if absolute path is needed, run `/Documents/DevFolder/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/platform-tools/android` and see if it launches `android`. If not, then it means you need absolute path to these folders (something that starts from `/home/...` I assume). Installing the SDK is just unzipping and adding to the path, yes.

Comment: Ok. Interesting. Now I put absolute paths. With that absolute path it starts the android application. Now if I run --> cordova platform add android--> I get--> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/util/plugins.js:28
    tmp_dir = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'plugman-tmp');
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'tmpdir'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the problem is related to the way the `PATH` to the `android` executable was defined. It is necessary to define these paths as absolute.

As for the `Object has no method 'tmpDir'` error, a quick google search revealed the following remedy: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phonegap/sKQ3MRrIpNg/dV6WYOTDDf0J

Answer (score 1):

It's an old thread, but thought I'd mention this... You have to open a new terminal window AFTER adding the export path in ~/.bash_profile - then "cordova platform add android" worked. :)

Comment: You can also just call the command `source ~/.bash_profile`, instead of opening a new terminal

Answer (score 0):

this one worked for me

A - open the file /Users//.bash_profile (for example running from that folder, the command vim .bash_profile... or simply from finder, finding the hidden file and opening it with a text editor)

B - add the following line make sure to adapt it to your ADT folder name and position (in my case I placed the original adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-xxxxx folder into Application and renamed it ADT)

export PATH=/Applications/ADT/sdk/tools:/Applications/ADT/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH

making sure to add :$PATH at the end